# SVN stuck in broken state

Tags: svn

I recently did a `svn add Foo/` which failed because there was a file (not a directory) called `Foo/.svn`

Without really thinking, I did `rm Foo/.svn; svn add Foo/`

This fails because "Foo is already under version control", although `svn status` shows

```
~ Foo
```

instead of

```
A Foo
```

I can't `svn commit` because of this. `svn add --force Foo/` doesn't help.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you Ack the content of .svn for Foo, you can see it in entries. This means it has been somewhat saved inside Svn local db, even if it failed to put its .svn db inside Foo.

An `svn revert Foo` forces Svn to remove it from its entries.

If you ask now for the status, your directory would be

```
?       Foo
```

You can then retry to `svn add` it and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing an update on that directory to recover the working copy to the state before you did the rm.

Comment: That will require a bothersome round of backups because there are other changes scattered in the other directories. I'm looking for a solution that only touches `Foo/`

Comment: I do not use svn directly, but use tortoise. With that you can update a single directory. As it uses svn underneath I assume that it is possible directly through the command line.

Comment: If you need to update "Foo/" without updating its children, use: --depth empty or --depth files - however, I recommend you do a bothersome round of backups regardless, just in case

Answer (score 0):

You can rename your directory where `Foo/` is situated. Then do `svn up` and manually merge your changes. Then you can add `Foo/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Since you just deleted `Foo/.svn` which just contains meta data, your local changes to files in `Foo/` are still there, you can follow these steps to preserve all your changes and fix the broken working copy:

1. `svn info` to get the revision number of the working copy, you will see something like
    `Revision: 94168`
2. `mv Foo Foo.bak` to backup the `broken` Foo directory
3. `svn up -r 94168 Foo` to re-checkout Foo from the remote repository, please replace `94168` with your actual revision number
4. `rsync -av --exclude='.svn' Foo.bak/ Foo/` to override the newly checked out Foo/ with the   files in previous backed up Foo.bak, but keep the right .svn meta data.
5. `svn status Foo`, then you should see all your local changes (if you indeed made changes) to Foo

no inner-file merge should be taken.